# Need suggestion removing data from dictionary

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary, tableview

I have a dictionary that is structured as follows:

```
[0:["var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value", 1:["var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value", 2:["var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value"]
```

I am using this to be displayed in a TableView:

```
cell.title.text = dict[indexPath.row]?["var1"]
```

The code above works fine, however when I am using .delete editing style to swipe to delete in a TableView, and remove the middle value it messes up my TableView because the dict now has 0: and 2: since we deleted the 1: so now the cellForRowAt is looking for 0: and 1: when the dict is actually 0: 2:

Swipe to delete code:

```
dict.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

Resulting dict:

```
[0:["var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value", 2:["var1":"var1Value","var2":"var2Value"]
```

Which in return will not let the tableView cells be shown properly.

The code below appears to be working. Would this work or possibly cause issues in the future?

```
func deleteFromArray(at:Int){
        var count = at
        while dict[count] != nil {
            dict[count] = dict[count+1]
            count += 1
        }
        
        ItemsTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Thank you for all the help

Comment: Don't use a `Dictionary`, use an `Array` instead.

Comment: @Larme I would but they need to be aspirated somehow into separate arrays. like I have 0: 1: and 2:

Comment: You can have an array of dictionaries. Or better an array of custom structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries don't work for the model for a table view or collection view. Use an array as Larme suggests.

You say something about needing separate arrays, but currently you don't have **any** arrays in your model. Right now what you have is a dictionary of dictionaries.

You can create a struct to represent a cell in your table view, and have the model be an array of those structs.

### Edit:

That might look something like this:

```
struct CellModel {
    let title: String
    let iconName: String
    let description: String
}

var tableViewModel: [CellModel] = [
    CellModel(title: "A Thing",
              iconName: "AnImageOfThing",
              description: "This is a thing to go in the table view"),
    CellModel(title: "Another Thing",
              iconName: "AnImageOfAnotherThing",
              description: "This is another thing to go in the table view"),
    CellModel(title: "Yet Another Thing",
              iconName: "AnImageOfYetAnotherThing",
              description: "This is yet another thing to go in the table view")
]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell: MyCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
        fatalError("Unable to dequeue cell")
    }
    let cellData = tableViewModel[indexPath.row] 
    cell.title = cellData.title
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: cellData.iconName)
    cell.descriptionField.text = cellData.description
    return cell
}
```